# Azure Active directory error - Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am struggling for last 4 hours to solve this issue which is coming out of these 4 lines of code:

```
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(Startup.authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
            var credential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(Startup.clientId, "SECRET_VALUE");
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync("https://MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com/TaskWebAPI", credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

- Line no 1 cannot result into any issue.
- Line no 2- Has only one value. Startup.authority which is https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenantName.
- Line no 3- ClientId is my web application client id. And in place of SECRETVALUE is 'one of the key that I generated in Keys section' for my WebAPP.
- LIne no 4- has resource AppId Key

It would be a great help if any of you help me debug these four lines.

Answer (score 0):

`AcquireTokenSilentAsync(...)` attempts to get you a token without showing any UI, and will fail if it cannot do so. It does this by looking in the token cache for valid tokens, and refreshes the token if necessary.  The action here is to catch the AdalException and retry with a acquireToken call.

```
catch (AdalException e) { 
    if (e.ErrorCode == "failed_to_acquire_token_silently") {
        // Do an AcquireToken call 
    }
}
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/active-directory/adal/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext) all the different overloads of AcquireToken.

Comment: Can you please share what call to make. I am inside webApp and at this moment client has already authenticated by WebApp. I cannot show UI at this point to user.

Comment: Try out [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/active-directory/adal/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_ClientCredential_). [Here's](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-useridentity) a complete Web App sample in .NET that may help.

Comment: Was there an error? Not the right overload for your use case?